Running tizen app in the background and vibrate the watch every hour or so
I am making an app that needs to be run in the background. It is basically a reminder after every x hours, While I am on the app the app send the notification without any issue, but as soon as I get out of it, nothing is running anymore.
I am very new to Tizen development. Any help is appreciated. Here is my config.xml. Also, I do not have any service running as I do not know how to.
I have the app running, I tried running a service but I do not even know how to do that. So I ended up adding background-category in the config.xml.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets"
    id="http://yourdomain/Interval"
    version="1.0.0"
    viewmodes="maximized">
    <tizen:application id="UmkARFYyuP.Interval" package="UmkARFYyuP" required_version="7.0"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>Interval</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/power"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/systemsettings"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/alarm"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/notification"/>
    <tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
    <tizen:background-category value="media" />
</widget>

Main.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var taskForm = document.getElementById('taskForm');
    var stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
    var message = document.getElementById('message');
    var intervalId;

    taskForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (intervalId) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }

        var taskName = document.getElementById('taskName').value;
        var interval = parseInt(document.getElementById('interval').value);

        var intervalMs = interval * 1000; // Convert to milliseconds

        message.textContent = `Reminder for ${taskName} set every ${interval} seconds`;

        intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            try {
                // Turn on the screen
                tizen.power.turnScreenOn();

                // Vibrate the device
                navigator.vibrate(1000); // Vibrate for 1 second

                // Create the notification properties
                var notificationDict = {
                    content: `Time to do: ${taskName}`,
                    vibration: true,
                    iconPath: "icon.png" // Optional: Set a path to your app's icon
                };

                // Create and post the notification
                var notification = new tizen.UserNotification('SIMPLE', 'Task Reminder', notificationDict);
                tizen.notification.post(notification);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error: " + error.message);
            }
        }, intervalMs);
    });

    stopButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (intervalId) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            message.textContent = 'Reminder stopped';
        }
    });
});

Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Task Reminder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Task Reminder</h1>
        <form id="taskForm">
            <label for="taskName">Task Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="taskName" required>
            
            <label for="interval">Remind Every (seconds):</label>
            <input type="number" id="interval" min="1" required>

            <button type="submit">Start</button>
            <button type="button" id="stopButton">Stop</button>
        </form>
        <p id="message"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


Service application is basically a sub-application provided with the same package.
Here is a concept explained. Here you can find step by step tutorial for creating a web service. Here you can find information how to make a reference between UI and service application in Tizen Studio.
With such package both UI and service application will be installed on the device.
Both applications can communicate with each other via messageport and service application can be controlled by application plugin (e.g. start/stop).
